# TensorFlow how to output predictions

Tags: tensorflow

I have for example X_train (70,513) X_test (70,2) Y_train(30,513) Y_train(30,2) how can I get the tensor-flow model that I trained to output (0,1) array values for the test values.

Comment: This might be answerable if you could post your code, so that we can see what we will have to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've not provided your model I'll assume you've done it the standard way.

I'm assuming after designing your model your output is stored in the tensor (say) `prediction`.

To see the prediction you need to create a session and feed in the required placeholders. This is how you do it:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={features: [[0.4, 1.1]]})
```

Since I don't know how your placeholders are defined, I made `features` a placeholder and feeded it a matrix of data.

Make sure you've initialized your variables using

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variable_initializer())
```